# What to do with the token from AWS cognito

Tags: javascript, authentication, amazon-cognito, google-signin

The idea is to perform login/authentication + autorization with AWS Cognito and Google Login as Federated entity.

Everything is done on the client side using AWS javascript SDK.

I can login using [https://.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=Google&redirect_uri=https://&response_type=token&client_id=<Client_id>](https://my-domain.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=Google&redirect_uri=https://&response_type=token&client_id=). I redirects me to my website and adds an **access_token** in the URL. I can get back AWS access and secret keys with the `CognitoIdentityCredentials` function.

Questions:

1. What to do with this **access_token**?
2. Which function do I need call to get the current user?
3. Do I need the `access_key` and `secret_key`?

Comment: It seems you confused many points. Please take a look on documentation again about Cognito Userpool and Cognito Identity.

Comment: I took your advice and it appears that I don't  need the identity part. But I don't understand how to use the token. I am using the API Gateway sdk

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it appears I was confused...

When logged in with Cognito, there are two JWT tokens in the URL (this part is important):

1. access_token
2. id_token

The `id_token` must be sent in the `Authorization` header when calling API Gateway to authorize the requests. The header is automatically set if you use the AWS Amplify SDK.

I will add more info when I manage to acheive the full flow from login/register to API Gateway requests.

Side note: I thing I got confused when I read all the pieces of code online (Github, Medium, etc.) where they all use Cognito Identity Pool after the login part.